# В чем смысл замыканий?

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю смысл замыканий

Зачем определять функции внутри функций?

Ведь говорилось,что функция-это действие,направленное на решение определенной проблемы,а не сразу нескольких

Comment: А где вам говорилось, что _функция - действие для решения определенной проблемы_ ? Вернее для каких языков программирования это говорилось ? Вот, теперь забудьте, в JS все не так, вообще все. Например JS нет понятия класса, как во многих других ООП языках. Понятие "класс" в JS заменено растянутым понятием "функция". И класс-функция "расчет координат" вполне решает определенную проблему, просто делает это набором функций, заключенных к контейнер, по счастливому совпадению то же являющийся функцией

Comment: Ну,когда читал книгу какую то,то там говорилось,что не нужно в одну функцию пихать все,что можно...возможно,это был Питон

Comment: замыкание - это один из способов передачи данных в функцию, которые необходимы для ее работы.

Comment: @GrommashTheHellscream На самом деле "функция" - это просто слово. спросите у математика, что такое функция. x=5y не значит "присвоить y умноженный на 5 x". Для математика эта запись означает  зависимость X от Y. У программистов принято считать "функцией" объединенный набор действий, принимающий аргументы и возвращающий результат. А в JS слово "function" означает одновременно и набор действий и объект и класс и думаю еще найдется, что можно так обозначить. В JS заменили десяток  ключевых слов одним. И надо заметить довольно удачно заменили, когда к этому привыкаешь - понимаешь, что это удобно

Answer (score 1):

> смысл замыканий

Например, надо выводить в лог сообщение, а также номер строки и время прошедшее с момента зарузки страницы.

---

Если не использовать замыкание, то надо определить следующую функцию

```
function log(timespan, lineNumber, msg) { 
   console.log(linNumber + " " + timespan + " " + msg;
}
```

и две переменные

```
var start = Date.now();
var lineNumber = 1;
```

Вызываем log так

```
log(Date.now()-start, lineNumber++, "один");
log(Date.now()-start, lineNumber++, "два");
```

Очевидно, что это неудобно.

---

Если использовать замыкание, то пишем так

```
var log = (function () {    // функция 1
   var start = Date.now();  // текущее значение сохранятся в start 
   var num = 1;             // также используется в замыкании в функции 2. 
   return function (msg) {  // функция 2 - сохраняется в var log
      console.log(num++ + " " + (Date.now()-start) + " " + msg);
   }
})();    // () -- вызываем функцию 1
```

Вызываем так

```
log("один");
log("два");
```

Результат

```
lineNumber   timespan     msg
------------------------------
1            0            один
2            1            два
```

---

Т.е. замыкание — это способ передачи данных в функцию.
Подробнее о замыканиях см. [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: "_Т.е. замыкание — это способ передачи данных в функцию._" -- передача данных - это только частный случай. На самом деле замыкание = функция + лексическая область видимости. Пример -- эмуляция статических переменных в функциях на JS

Comment: @DmitriySimushev _"лексическая область видимости"_ -- в области видимости находятся  переменные, в которых находятся какие-то значения (строки, числа и т.д., включая функции) -- и переменные в итоге используются для получения доступа к данным.

Comment: По-вашему каррирование тоже суть передача данных в функцию? А частичное применение?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev _"эмуляция статических переменных в функциях на JS"_ -- пример определения статической переменной x и ее использование. `var Test = (function () { function Test() { } Test.prototype.run = function (y) { return Test.x + y; }; Test.x = 1; return Test;})();` -- из-за Test.x - это не похоже не замыкание.

Comment: Я о вот таком методе `var f = (function() {var staticX = 0;  return function() {staticX++; /* какие-то действия */};})();` -- вполне себе замыкание

Comment: @DmitriySimushev _"Я о вот таком методе var f = (function() {var staticX = 0; return function() {staticX++;};})();"_ -- staticX - это переменная. хранит данные. при запуске второй функции, эти данные используются. staticX можно передать в функцию через параметры (см. в ответе function log(timespan,..), или через замыкание (см. var log = (function...)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34749/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-stack).

Answer (score 1):

1 - Так как в javascript нет модификаторов доступа, то лучшим способом для достижения инкапсуляции можно назвать [замыкания](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript). Стоит обратить внимание на iife.

```
var SomeNameModule = (function(a,b){
  function SomeName(){
      this.h,this.c;// some init logic   
  }
  SomeName.prototype.someMethod = function(){
     return a * b * this.c * this.h
  };
  return SomeName;
})(10, 20)
```

2 - Замыкания являются неотъемлемой частью функционального программирования, что позволяет использовать подходы, называемые curring и частичное применение. Очень удобно, когда имеешь дело с функциями высшего порядка

```
(function(indent){
   var httpProm = someRequest();
   httpProm.then(httpRespHandler(indent))
})(indent);
function httpRespHandler(indent){
    return function(resp){
        return JSON.stringify(resp.data, null, indent);
    }
}
```

3 - До введения let и const с помощью iife можно было обеспечить block scope, тем самым мы можем изолировать приватные переменные (логику) внутри дополнительных функций, а если внутри них создатются временные тяжелые объекты, то и выиграть в утилизации памяти.

```
if(a > 10){
 (function(){
    //some code, init and so on
 })();//нет высплывания объявлений
} else{
 (function(){
    //some another code, init and so on
 })();//нет высплывания объявлений
}
```

4 - Создание дополнительных функций внутри другой функции и вынисение какого-то логически связанного функционала внутрь этих сурогатных функций, позволяет организовывать код лучше

```
(function(){
   return meaningfulName1() * meaningfulName2() * meaningfulName3();
   function meaningfulName1(){
    //10 lines of code
   }
   function meaningfulName2(){
    //10 lines of code
   }
   function meaningfulName3(){
    // 10 lines of code
   }
})()
```

реализация отделена от использования, ни строчки бесполезных комментариев.
Это все то, что я использую в повседневной практике.

Comment: По-хорошему, не хватает конкретики о том, что же такое замыкание (безотносительно примеров из практики).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Вопрос был не о даче определения, а о смысле (местах)  их использования

Comment: @DmitriySimushev _"не хватает конкретики о том, что же такое замыкание (безотносительно примеров из практики)"_ -- напишите свой ответ. а без примеров сложно бывает понять о чем говорят, т.к. одно и тоже может называться по разному.

Answer (score -1):

Если функция использует однотипные действия и эти действия должны быть только у главной функции, то создаются подфункции.

Подфункции располагаются внутри главной функции, чтобы другие функции не могли испортить структуру.

К примеру, есть функция, которая должна создать таблицу календаря за месяц. И вам нужно, чтобы суббота и воскресенье были выделены красным цветом.

1. Создаете функцию "календарь таблица"
2. Внутри нее создаете функцию "проверка дня на субботу и воскресенье".
3. Создаете вторую внутреннюю функцию "создать стиль для выделенного дня".

Теперь представьте, что эти 2 подфункции были бы объявлены вне функции "календарь таблица". Получилось бы так, что любой смог бы сделать произвольный день недели выделенным, так как внутри функции "создать стиль для выделенного дня" нет проверки на субботу и воскресенье.

Как-то так...

Comment: Вы так и не ответили на вопрос что такое замыкание. А в отрыве от замыканий создание функций внутри функций -- тривиальное занятие.